# Can't access to wamp/xampp apache localhost:80 WINDOWS 10

Tags: apache, networking, localhost, windows-10

I recently upgrade my Windows 7 to Windows 10 (9). I need to use Apache server for web development. But for some reason I can't access it via web browser.

First I tried to look in the firewall and antivirus settings. It looks fine. I've tried reinstall xampp then I tried Wamp. Nothing working. I'tried 3 web browsers Edge, Opera, Chrome. Then I tried to find if some application is blocking port 80. So I disabled Skype, IIS. Then I tried different ports 8080,9080,123. Still can't access it via browser, but ping works.

Then I disable preference of Ipv6 and I prefer IPV4 now. I've changed HOSTS file so only 127.0.0.1 localhost is uncommented.

Only problem occurs when I try run wamp my internet access became unavailible and a have to restart computer to access internet again.

Has anyone here have same problem, because according to everything I ve done it seems apache server and network settings is correct.

Maybe problem is somewhere else?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with clean Windows 10 installation.